# Tabs inside a tab does not work

Tags: jquery, html, css, materialize

https://codepen.io/simii/pen/grvxbE

Heres the codepen.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <ul class="tabs2">
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3 disabled"><a href="#test3">Disabled Tab</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="test1" class="col s12">Test 1</div>
    <div id="test2" class="col s12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3 disabled"><a href="#test3">Disabled Tab</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="test1" class="col s12">Test 1</div>
    <div id="test2" class="col s12">Test 2</div>
    <div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
    <div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 4</div>
  </div>
        </div>
    <div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
    <div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 4</div>
  </div>


 $(document).ready(function(){
$('ul.tabs2').tabs();
$('ul.tabs').tabs();
});
```

Its using materialize framework with jquery. I don't know what to change to make it work.

Tabs inside another tab

Comment: what exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Tabbing works by default on links, buttons, form elements, etc.

In order to have them work on other elements, add the `tabindex` attribute:

However, if you have buttons or forms on your page, you'll have to be careful that your tab indexes work alongside those elements - that tab order is "correct".

Comment: Right but the problem here is that his tabs (meant as component) dont work at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
```

In this section, `href` is the key player, the ID that you provide has to be unique for inner tables also.

Please have a look on the updated Codepen, where inner tabs are also functional

https://codepen.io/KunalMZ/pen/ZOoVjp?editors=1010